# Texture UVs not sent to shaders correctly

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, vbo, texture-mapping

I am rendering a mesh using GLSL shaders and a VBO, and the VBO stores 4 attributes; positionXYZ, normalXYZ, textureUV, colourRGBA. Everything works, except for the UVs (possibly the normals too, but I haven't got a way to test them yet).

What is happening is, the texture UV positions in the array are offset to the normal x and y position in the array. The array is structured as `VVVNNNTTCCCC` (vertex position, normal, texture, colour) by the way. I am pretty sure that the problem is somewhere in sending the VBO to the shaders. I know for certain that the data in the VBO is in the correct order.

This is my rendering code:

The VBO class

```
public final class Mesh
{
    public static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
    public static final int FLOATS_PER_POSITION = 3;
    public static final int FLOATS_PER_NORMAL = 3;
    public static final int FLOATS_PER_TEXTURE = 2;
    public static final int FLOATS_PER_COLOUR = 4;
    public static final int VERTEX_SIZE_FLOATS = FLOATS_PER_POSITION + FLOATS_PER_NORMAL + FLOATS_PER_TEXTURE + FLOATS_PER_COLOUR;
    public static final int VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES = VERTEX_SIZE_FLOATS * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;

    public static final int POSITION_OFFSET_FLOATS = 0;
    public static final int NORMAL_OFFSET_FLOATS = POSITION_OFFSET_FLOATS + FLOATS_PER_POSITION;
    public static final int TEXTURE_OFFSET_FLOATS = NORMAL_OFFSET_FLOATS + FLOATS_PER_NORMAL;
    public static final int COLOUR_OFFSET_FLOATS = TEXTURE_OFFSET_FLOATS + FLOATS_PER_TEXTURE;
    public static final int POSITION_OFFSET_BYTES = POSITION_OFFSET_FLOATS * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    public static final int NORMAL_OFFSET_BYTES = NORMAL_OFFSET_FLOATS * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    public static final int TEXTURE_OFFSET_BYTES = TEXTURE_OFFSET_FLOATS * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    public static final int COLOUR_OFFSET_BYTES = COLOUR_OFFSET_FLOATS * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    public static final int POSITION_STRIDE_BYTES = VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES;
    public static final int NORMAL_STRIDE_BYTES = VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES;
    public static final int TEXTURE_STRIDE_BYTES = VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES;
    public static final int COLOUR_STRIDE_BYTES = VERTEX_SIZE_BYTES;

    public final static int VERTICES_PER_FACE = 3;

    public static final int ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_POSITION = 0;
    public static final int ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_NORMAL = 1;
    public static final int ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_TEXTURE = 2;
    public static final int ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_COLOUR = 3;

    private int vaoID;
    private int iboID;
    private int indexCount;

    private Mesh(int vaoID, int iboID, int indexCount)
    {
        this.vaoID = vaoID;
        this.iboID = iboID;
        this.indexCount = indexCount;
    }

    public void draw(AbstractShaderProgram shader, Texture texture)
    {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        if (texture != null) texture.bind(shader);
        else Texture.MISSING_TEXTURE.bind(shader);

        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_POSITION);
//        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_NORMAL);
//        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_TEXTURE);
//        glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_COLOUR);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_FLOAT, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_POSITION);
//        glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_NORMAL);
//        glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_TEXTURE);
//        glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_COLOUR);

        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    public static Mesh compile(List<Face> faces)
    {
        if (faces.size() <= 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to compile mesh. No faces were provided.");

        HashMap<Vertex, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
        int vertexCount = 0;


        for (Face face : faces)
        {
            for (Vertex vertex : face.getVertices())
            {
                if (!indexMap.containsKey(vertex))
                {
                    indexMap.put(vertex, vertexCount++);
                    vertices.add(vertex);
                }
            }
        }

        int indicesCount = faces.size() * VERTICES_PER_FACE;

        int dataSize = vertexCount * VERTEX_SIZE_FLOATS;
        FloatBuffer vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(dataSize);
        if (vertexData == null)
            System.err.println("Failed to allocate FloatBuffer with size " + dataSize);

        for (Vertex vertex : vertices)
        {
            vertexData.put(vertex.getPosition().x);
            vertexData.put(vertex.getPosition().y);
            vertexData.put(vertex.getPosition().z);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getNormal() == null ? 1.0F : vertex.getNormal().x);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getNormal() == null ? 1.0F : vertex.getNormal().y);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getNormal() == null ? 1.0F : vertex.getNormal().z);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getTexture() == null ? 0.0F : vertex.getTexture().x);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getTexture() == null ? 0.0F : vertex.getTexture().y);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getColour() == null ? 1.0F : vertex.getColour().getRGBA().x);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getColour() == null ? 1.0F : vertex.getColour().getRGBA().y);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getColour() == null ? 1.0F : vertex.getColour().getRGBA().z);
//            vertexData.put(vertex.getColour() == null ? 1.0F : vertex.getColour().getRGBA().w);
        }
        vertexData.flip();

        IntBuffer indices = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indicesCount);

        for (Face face : faces)
        {
            for (Vertex vertex : face.getVertices())
            {
                int index = indexMap.get(vertex);
                indices.put(index);
            }
        }
        indices.flip();

        int vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

        int vboID = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_POSITION, FLOATS_PER_POSITION, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
//        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_NORMAL, FLOATS_PER_NORMAL, GL_FLOAT, false, NORMAL_STRIDE_BYTES, NORMAL_OFFSET_BYTES);
//        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_TEXTURE, FLOATS_PER_TEXTURE, GL_FLOAT, false, TEXTURE_STRIDE_BYTES, TEXTURE_OFFSET_BYTES);
//        glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_COLOUR, FLOATS_PER_COLOUR, GL_FLOAT, false, COLOUR_STRIDE_BYTES, COLOUR_OFFSET_BYTES);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        int iboID = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        return new Mesh(vaoID, iboID, indicesCount);
    }
}
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 vertPosition;
in vec3 vertNormal;
in vec2 vertTexture;
in vec4 vertColour;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

out vec3 pVertPosition;
out vec3 pVertNormal;
out vec2 pVertTexture;
out vec4 pVertColour;

void main()
{
    pVertPosition = vertPosition;
    pVertNormal = vertNormal;
    pVertTexture = vertTexture;
    pVertColour = vertColour;

    gl_Position = vec4(vec3(vertPosition.xy + vertTexture, vertPosition.z), 1.0);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 ppVertPosition;
in vec3 ppVertNormal;
in vec2 ppVertTexture;
in vec4 ppVertColour;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, ppVertTexture);
}
```

There is a geometry shader in between these, but it is currently redundant and just pases the information straight to the fragment shader (that is why the out and in variables don't match.) Also, the reason the textureUV is added to the vertex position in the fragment shader was to debug what the texture UV values being passed actually were. This is how I know the UVs are offset to the normal xy. If I put the texture UVs into the normal xy, they work perfectly fine.

If there is any extra code you would like to see, that I haven't included, I'll add it. I haven't added everything, for example, the whole VBO class, because it is too much code. I have only included what I think is relevant and where I think the problem is.

Edit #1:
The variable locations in the shader, such as `vertPosition` and `vertNormal` are bound. This is my code to bind them

```
glBindAttribLocation(program, Mesh.ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_POSITION, "vertPosition");
glBindAttribLocation(program, Mesh.ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_NORMAL, "vertNormal");
glBindAttribLocation(program, Mesh.ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_TEXTURE, "vertTexture");
glBindAttribLocation(program, Mesh.ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_COLOUR, "vertColour");
```

Changing the vertex shader to use layouts, like so, yields the ex\ct same result;

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertTexture;
layout(location = 3) in vec4 vertColour;
```

Edit #2
I decided to post the entire Mesh class, rather than just parts of it. I have also tried to implement VAOs instead of VBOs, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing standard pipeline functionality with custom shader variables.

Calling `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);` tells OpenGL to use a certain data bind point, all good.

Calling `glVertexPointer(` tells OpenGL where to find its vertices. Since you enabled the correct array previously, all is still good.

Then we get to the vertex shader and you use `in vec3 vertPosition;` but GLSL doesn't know that you want your vertex data there. Sure, we can see the name is "vertPosition", but GLSL shouldn't have to guess the data you want based on the variable name of course! Instead, the default pipeline behavior for GLSL is to use `gl_Vertex`, a pre built GLSL variable tied to `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`.

So why does it work for positions? Sheer luck with the variables you define being allocated the pre-built constants by chance, I guess.

What you should do is switch `glEnableClientState` to `glEnableVertexAttribArray`, use [Layouts](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) to assign each variable a number, and call `glVertexAttribPointer` instead of `glVertexPointer` to link that number to the correct data.

Now, the variables you declared, like `vertPosition`, point to the right data in your buffers, not by chance, but because you told them to!

This is the correct way to do things in modern OpenGL, using the pre built variables like `gl_Vertex` and functions like `glEnableClientState` is considered old and bad because its inflexible.

You can also omit the layouts (because it requires OGL 4+, which not everyone has), but that requires some more work before linking the shaders.

Good luck!

[More info on converting your code](https://www.gamedev.net/topic/629803-glvertexpointer-glnormalpointer-and-gltexcoordpointer-deprecated-correct-use/)

(I hope im right with this, I cant comment to actually verify that this is the issue)

Comment: Umm, sorry I didn't include this code, but it isn't shear luck that it works. I have `vertPosition`, `vertNormal` etc bound, I just didn't post that code on the question. Sorry. My code for this looks like: `glBindAttribLocation(program,Mesh.ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_POSITION, "vertPosition");`

Comment: Haha, ok, unfortunate. I still recommend you remove the clientstates and use `glEnableVertexAttribArray(Mesh.ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_POSITION )` instead, it may still cause issues. And use `glVertexAttribPointer ` with the indices you have specified. So `glVertexAttribPointer(Mesh.ATTRIBUTE_LOCATION_POSITION ....`

Comment: glVertexAttribPointer should replace glVertexPointer and the others, just for clarification.

Comment: So, I cant seem to get the VAO to work. It just renders nothing. I have posted the entire class in the main post in it's current state.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working... finally. I have no idea what the initial problem was with the VBO, but once I switched to use a VAO, and not render with `glClientState`, it worked fine. Also, the problem I was having with the VAO not rendering anything what-so-ever was the line:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_FLOAT, 0);
```

should have been

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```